# Problem connecting to MS SQL server 2000 with Spring Boot

Tags: spring

## I try connect to ms sql server 2000 and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Unfortunately, I can not use another server. Help me please.

[server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsCvx.png)

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aESvF.png)

### Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-J1EE59P\\EGOR;databaseName=dekanat
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

### Grandle file

```
 dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

        //compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server')
        //compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        compile("org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.1.1")
        compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: 'jtds', version: '1.2'

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '1.7.2'
        compile('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
        compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
        compile group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '0.7.5'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter
       // compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
        testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.0.0.jre8'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds
        compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: 'jtds', version: '1.3.1'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4
        testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0.0'
```

### Errors

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
```

Comment: i think for msql 2000 driver name was: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver can you try that..

Comment: @kj007 Thank you. I tried, but this is not a solution. Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Comment: check the correct ms jdbc version for sql 2000 as 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0.0' should work after 2005..

Comment: @kj007 Everywhere they write that if I need a driver for server 2000, update the server for 2005

Comment: what java version and spring boot version you are using and can you remove testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.0.0.jre8' and make it compile from testCompile " testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0.0'" and have old driver name you had earlier..

Comment: you can try that but issue is related to driver for 2000 as jdbc and jdbc4(2005) they have changed driver name to what you currently using

Comment: then I will recommend you downlaod 2000 jdbc driver and add in your classpath as lib and remove gradle entries.

Comment: https://downloads.avaya.com/elmodocs2/ir/28432.htm

Comment: @kj007 springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE' , java version "1.8.0_161". thanks, I'll try

Comment: Sqljdb4 works after equal java 6 but for 2005 or greater so downloading 2000 jdbc jar make sense and adding in class path should work then not require jdbc4 entry in gradle otherwise will conflict

Comment: @kj007 I downloaded this driver and added it separately and deleted the dependencies. And now org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Comment: Have you changed now driver name what I said in first comment

Comment: @kj007 yes, but it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have following dependency on your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I used this dependency in gradle compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '4.0.0'